# File Exists Script Task for SQL Server SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, file-system, error-handling, ssis

I have an SSIS package for SQL Server 2008. In this package, I need to verify that a file exists that matches a pattern of `SomeFileName_*.txt` where the wild card replaces a `YYYYMMDD` date. It doesn't matter what the date of the file is, just that any file matching that pattern exists. If a file does not exist, I need to fail the package before using the built in "For each file loop" task. This allows our server to alert me to the package failure.

It's a pretty simple bit of code, but it has a huge smell. I'm catching `Exception`. I think I'm doing it for the right reasons though. Basically, I'm saying that if ***any*** exception gets thrown, fail the script task, and thus the package. Is this a case where it's *okay* to catch all exceptions??? For reference, these are the [possible exceptions that Directory.GetFiles can throw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx).

Of course, I'm pretty new to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), so please let me know if I'm doing anything stupid. (Yes, I know I'm programming in `Main`, but this is short and sweet. I don't see the harm just this once...)

```
public void Main()
{

    try
    {
        string sourcePath = Dts.Variables["User::sourcePath"].Value.ToString();
        string searchPattern = Dts.Variables["User::searchPattern"].Value.ToString();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            Dts.Log(string.Format("No file(s) found in '{0}' with a pattern of '{1}'.", sourcePath, searchPattern), 0, null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        Dts.Log(string.Format("Script Task encountered an unexpected error. Souce: {0}. Message: {1).", e.Source, e.Message), 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's okay. If you need to catch any exception then you should essentially catch them all.

The reason you typically avoid this and use the most concrete exceptions possible is to provide exception-specific behaviour: an accurate log message or a different continuation once it has been logged.

If all your exceptions are handled the same way then you can just use the catch-all. Note that you can always add a specific handler afterwards because the catch clauses are evaluated linearly.

Comment: I didn't know that they're evaluated linearly. Thanks!